# Find all solutions to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {91},\ 91 = 7\cdot 13$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I split this into $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {7}$ and $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {13}$.

For $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {7}$, i did:
$$ (\pm1 )^2\equiv 1\pmod{7}$$ $$(\pm2 )^2\equiv 4\pmod{7}$$ $$(\pm3 )^2\equiv 2\pmod{7}$$ Which shows that the solutions to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {7}$ are $\pm1$.

For $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {13}$, i did:
$$ (\pm1 )^2\equiv 1\pmod{13}$$ $$(\pm2 )^2\equiv 4\pmod{13}$$ $$(\pm3 )^2\equiv 9\pmod{13}$$ $$ (\pm4 )^2\equiv 3\pmod{13}$$ $$(\pm5 )^2\equiv {-1}\pmod{13}$$ $$(\pm6 )^2\equiv 10\pmod{13}$$Which shows that the solutions to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {13}$ are $\pm1$.

Thus, I concluded that the solutions to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod {91}$ must be $\pm1$. I thought that $\pm1$ were the only solutions, but apparently I am incorrect! How do I go about finding the other solutions to this congruence?

Comment: Hint: CRT. See  [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477365/number-theory-x2-equiv-1-pmod140?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $x\equiv\pm1\mod7$ and $x\equiv\pm1\mod13$. For all the solutions, you have to consider the systems:
$$x\equiv1\mod7$$
$$x\equiv1\mod13$$
and
$$x\equiv-1\mod7$$
$$x\equiv1\mod13$$
and
$$x\equiv1\mod7$$
$$x\equiv-1\mod13$$
and
$$x\equiv-1\mod7$$
$$x\equiv-1\mod13$$
as each system will get you a valid answer. I think you only had the first and the last systems and that you only considered the cases where the signs were similar.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the other solutions to be $\pm 27$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the possibility that $x \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ but $x \equiv -1 \pmod {13}$, and so on. (In other words, your mistake was to assume that the $\pm1$ modulo $7$ was the same sign as $\pm1$ modulo $13$.)

Also note that for any prime $p$, if $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then we can rewrite this as $$x^2 - 1 \equiv (x+1)(x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod p.$$

Thus we get $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$, showing that it isn't necessary to run through all the values of $x^2$ to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

By CRT the solutions $\,x\equiv \pm1\pmod{\! 7},\ x\equiv \pm1\pmod{\!13}$ combine to  $\,4\,$ solutions mod $91,\,$ viz $\,x\equiv (\color{#c00}{{\bf 1,1}}),\,(\color{#0a0}{-1,-1}),\,(1,-1),\,(-1,1)\pmod{\!7,13},$ cf. "$\rm\color{#90f}{Combining}$" below. The first two  have solution $\,\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\,$ and $\,\color{#0a0}{-1}\,$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242). Finally solve $\,x\equiv (1,-1)$, and $(-1,1)\equiv -(1,-1)$ is its *negative,* i.e. $\,x\equiv 1\pmod{\!7},\,x\equiv -1\pmod{\!13}\ [\!\iff -x\equiv -1\pmod{\!7},\ {-}x\equiv 1\pmod{\!13}\:\!]$ to get $\,x\equiv \pm 27\pmod{91},\,$ the *nontrivial* $(\not\equiv \pm 1)$ sqrt's of $1,\bmod 91$.

**Remark** $ $ In more complex cases it's often easier to apply CRT  using generic (symbolic) values, then plug in specific values for all combinations, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864763/242) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2052030/242) and [many here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+crt+combination+root+mod).

Conversely, given any nontrivial $(\not\equiv \pm1)$ square-root of $1\pmod{\!n}$ we can quickly compute a nontrivial factorization of $n\,$ [we [can do that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) for any polynomial of $\,\deg k\,$ with $\,> k\,$ roots].

---

$\rm\color{#90f}{Combining}$ $ $ If $\,m,n\,$ are coprime then, by CRT, solving a polynomial $\,f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\!mn}\,$ is equivalent to solving $\,f(x)\equiv 0\,$ mod $\,m\,$ and mod $\,n.\,$ By CRT, each combination of a root $\,r_i\bmod m\,$ and a root $\,s_j\bmod n\,$ corresponds to a unique root $\,t_{ij}\bmod mn,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(x)\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{\!mn}&\overset{\,\,\rm CRT}\iff& \begin{array}{}f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! m}\\f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! n}\end{array} \\ 
&\,\,\iff&  \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_1,\ldots,r_k\pmod{\! m}\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}\\x\equiv s_1,\ldots,s_\ell\pmod{\! n}\end{array}\\ 
&\,\,\iff& \left\{ \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_i\pmod{\! m}\\x\equiv s_j\pmod {\! n}\end{array} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}^{\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}}\\
&\overset{\,\,\rm CRT}\iff& \left\{ x\equiv t_{i j}\!\!\pmod{\!mn} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$