# Find the smallest integer $n$ greater than $1$ such that the last $3$ digits of $n^2$ are the same as the last $3$ digits of $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the smallest integer $n$ greater than $1$ such that the last $3$ digits of $n^2$ are the same as the last $3$ digits of $n$.

So far I've got $n^2 = 1000k + n$ which means $n^2 ≡ n \mod 1000$. I  don't know how to proceed since 1000 seems to be a bit high.

Comment: More generally, for last $m$ digits, this is "[least $m$-digit automorphic number](https://oeis.org/A094190)". Where, $m=3$ gives $n^2=\color{red}{376}^2=141\color{red}{376}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$n(n-1)\equiv0\pmod{2^35^3}$$

As $(n,n-1)=1,$  we can have following four cases

$$n\equiv0\pmod{2^35^3}$$

$$n-1\equiv0\pmod{2^35^3}$$

$$n-1\equiv0\pmod{2^3}\text{  and } n\equiv0\pmod{5^3}$$

$$n-1\equiv0\pmod{5^3}\text{  and } n\equiv0\pmod{2^3}$$

For the last two cases use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)

Answer (score 0):

$n^2 \equiv n \pmod{1000}$ can be rearranged to $n(n-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{1000}$
Since $n$ and $n-1$ are coprime and $1000 = 2^3 \cdot 5^3$, what can you conclude about $n$?

A small amount of case analysis may be necessary.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, I think you're failing to use the coprimality.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $n\geq 100$. Since $$125\cdot 8\mid n(n-1)\implies 125 \mid n\;\;\; \vee \;\;\;125\mid n-1$$ and $$8 \mid n\;\;\; \vee \;\;\;8\mid n-1$$

so $$n\in \{100,101,125,126,250,251,375,376,...\}$$ so ...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but, for example, $8\nmid100\land8\nmid99$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner   So? $1\in \{1,2,3,...\}$ but $1\ne 2$ and $1\ne 3$...

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

$(\pm1)^2\equiv1,(\pm2)^2\equiv4,(\pm3)^2\equiv9,(\pm4)^2\equiv6\pmod{10}$

The last digit of $n^2,n$ will be same if $n=10m,10m+1,10m+5,10m+6$

$(10m+6)^2\equiv36+20m\pmod{100}$

We need $10m+6\equiv36+20m\pmod{100}\iff10m\equiv-30\pmod{100}\iff m\equiv-3\pmod{10}$

WLOG $m=10r-3$

$10m+6=10(10r-3)+6=100r-24$

$(100r-24)^2\equiv576-4800r\pmod{1000}\equiv576+200r$

We need $100r-24\equiv576+200r\pmod{1000}\iff100r\equiv-600\equiv400\pmod{1000}\iff r\equiv4\pmod{10}$

$r=10s+4\implies100r-24=100(10s+4)-24=1000s+376$

Similarly for $10m+1,10m+5$

Answer (score 0):

As [explained here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3250900/242) we solve a modular quadratic via CRT as in the Remark below, here using also that a prime power   $\,p^n\mid x(x\!-\!1)\iff p^n\mid x\ $ or $\ p^n\mid x\!-\!1,\,$ by $\,x,\,x\!-\!1\,$ coprime, which yields

$$x(x\!-\!1)\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{\!8\cdot 125}\iff \begin{align} &x\equiv 0,1\!\!\!\pmod{\!8}\\ &x\equiv 0,1\!\!\!\pmod{\!125}\end{align}\qquad\qquad $$

By the Remark they combine to $\,4\,$ roots $\,x\equiv (\color{#90f}{{0,0}}),\,(\color{#0a0}{1,1}),\,(0,1),\,(1,0)\,$ mod $(8,125).\,$  By [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) the first two lift to $\,x\equiv \color{#90f}{0},\,\color{#0a0}{1} \pmod{\!1000},\,$  the third root $\,(0,1)\bmod (8,125)$ lifts by CRT as

$\!\bmod\, \color{#c00}{8}\!:\:\  0 \equiv\, x \equiv 1+125\,\color{#c00}k \equiv 1-3k \iff 3k\equiv1\equiv9 \iff \color{#c00}{k \equiv 3}$

hence we infer $\ x = 1+125(\color{#c00}{3+8}n) = 376+1000n,\ $ so $\ (0,1)\,\mapsto 376.\,$ Like in Vieta, the final  $4\rm'th$ root $\,(1,0)\,$ is easy using $\, (1,0) + \smash[b]{\underbrace{(0,1)^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\!\!\!}_{\large 376}}\equiv \smash[b]{\underbrace{(1,1)}_{\large 1}}_{\phantom{._{|_{|_{|_|}}}}}\!\!\!\!\!$ $\Rightarrow (1,0)\,\mapsto\, 1\!-\!376\equiv 625$

**Remark** $ $ For more complex examples it is usually easier to solve the CRT system first for generic (symbolic) roots, then plug in the specific root values for all combinations, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864763/242) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2052030/242)

If $\,m,n\,$ are coprime then, by CRT, solving a polynomial $\,f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\!mn}\,$ is equivalent to solving $\,f(x)\equiv 0\,$ mod $\,m\,$ and mod $\,n.\,$ By CRT, each combination of a root $\,r_i\bmod m\,$ and a root $\,s_j\bmod n\,$ corresponds to a unique root $\,t_{ij}\bmod mn,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(x)\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{\!mn}&\overset{\,\,\rm CRT}\iff& \begin{array}{}f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! m}\\f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! n}\end{array} \\ 
&\,\,\iff&  \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_1,\ldots,r_k\pmod{\! m}\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}\\x\equiv s_1,\ldots,s_\ell\pmod{\! n}\end{array}\\ 
&\,\,\iff& \left\{ \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_i\pmod{\! m}\\x\equiv s_j\pmod {\! n}\end{array} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}^{\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}}\\
&\overset{\,\,\rm CRT}\iff& \left\{ x\equiv t_{i j}\!\!\pmod{\!mn} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think you meant to type $\color{red}{3+8}$ where you typed $\color{red}{2+8}$

Comment: @J.W.T Tx, typo fixed. I highly doubt that one character typo is the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

In a practical way, the number $N$ is, $\forall p>=0$ $$p\times1000+(100a+10b+c)$$
We can ignore the prefix $p\times1000$ as it doesn't affect the $3$ last digits of $N^2$

We want $c$ and the last digit of $c^2$ to be equal
$$c\equiv c^2\pmod{10}$$
That only works for 
$$\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c\in\{0,1,5,6\}}$$
For $b$, we want the second digit of $(10b+c)^2$ to be equal to $b$ (note: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the integer part of $x$)
$$b\equiv \lfloor\frac{(10b+c)^2}{10}\rfloor\pmod{10}$$
Plugging our $c$ values, $b$ can only be $0$ if $c=0$, also $0$ if $c=1$, $2$ if $c=5$ and $7$ if $c=6$
$$\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c=0\implies b = 0}\\
\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c=1\implies b = 0}\\
\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c=5\implies b = 2}\\
\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c=6\implies b = 7}\\$$
Not so many valid candidates after all.
Finally, for $a$, we want the third digit of $(100a+10b+c)^2$ to be equal to $a$ 
$$a\equiv \lfloor\frac{(100a+10b+c)^2}{100}\rfloor\pmod{10}$$
We have only $4$ cases to check since $b$ and $c$ values are strongly correlated. Injecting our $(b,c)$ values,we get
$$\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c=b=0\implies a = 0}\\
\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c=1,b=0\implies a = 0}\\
\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c=5,b=2\implies a = 6}\\
\bbox[7px,border:1px solid gray]{c=6,b=7\implies a = 3}\\$$
Meaning the last $3$ digits of $N$ can be any of
$$000, 001, 625, 376$$
Since we want the smaller valid number $>1$, the answer is
$$\bbox[8px,border:1px solid blue]{376}\\$$

Comment: Is it possible to know the downvote reason, to improve the answer?

Comment: I think this is overall a reasonable elementary strategy.  I'm not the downvoter, but I think it would be improved by adding some more detail about how you find the possible $b$ values for a given $c$.  Are you able to make use of the equation at all, or are you just using trial-and-error with each possible digit?