# Quadratic congruence equation of form $aX^{2} + bX \equiv c$(mod m)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So far i only encountered linear congruence equations of the form $aX \equiv b$(mod m) or $aX^{2}+bX+c \equiv 0$(mod m). I can't find any answers on how to proceed with this kind of equation.

Any tip or hint would help.

Comment: Hint: complete the square. Does your textbook discuss quadratic residues and nonresidues? Quadratic congruences should be discussed in that same section.

Comment: We only discussed when linear congruence equations have solutions and how many. Also we went over the Chinese remainder theorem, but none of the above form. I will try what you said, thanks!

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2052030/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3250900/242) for how to use CRT to lift the roots mod $p^k\ \ $