# How to solve $x^2 - 1$ in ring $\mathbb{Z}/700\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: modules

How to solve $x^2 - 1$ in  ring $\mathbb{Z}/700\mathbb{Z}$

I know China's theorem about mods, but i doesn't understand how to use it, when i need to find root for this problem.

But i can find for example $7^{22^{34}}$ mod 567, or something like this

Comment: E.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2041335/242)  The same technique applies.