# A nine digit number in which every digit occurs except zero and which ends in $5$ cannot be a square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

A nine digit number in which every digit occurs except zero and which ends in $5$ cannot be a square.
I was reading the solution from Arthur Engel's book Problem Solving Strategies . I didn't get the idea of assuming $A=10a+5$. Also, by assuming $A$ and then finding about A, how is that enough in solving the problem since $D=A^2$  .The solution is as follows:

> Suppose there is such a  nine digit number $D$ so that $D=A^2.A=10a+5$ which means $A^2=100a^2+100a+25 =100a(a+1)+25$. Consequences:
> The next to last digit is 2 ,
> The third digit from the right in $D$ is one ,which can be the final digit in a(a+1) that is 0,2,or 6 .See the table below:
> $a=0$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=0$

$a=1$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=0$

$a=2$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=2$

$a=3$

$a(a+1)(mod10)6$

$a=4$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=2$

$a=5$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=0$

$a=6$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=0$

$a=7$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=2$

$a=8$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=6$

$a=9$

$a(a+1)(mod10)=2$

But $0$ cannot occur ,and $5$ has already occured.

Comment: saying $A$ ends in $5$ is equivalent to saying that it is of the form $10a+1$. And tehy are supposing that it is a perfect square in the hopes of deriving a contradiction.

Comment: @lulu You surely mean "... is of the form $10a+5$ ..."

Comment: You misquoted the value for $A^2$ (which I have corrected).

Comment: "$D = A^2$ ends in $5$" means $A^2 = 10n+5,\,$ so $\,5\mid A^2\overset{Euclid}\Longrightarrow 5\mid A,\,$ so $A$ ends in $0$ or $5$; but only the latter has square ending in $5\ $ (or use digit $0$ excluded by hypothesis). More algorithmically you could solve $\,x^2\equiv 5\pmod{\!10}\,$ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2041335/242). Of course you could also brute force check all $10$ possible digits, but that's less instructive.

Comment: @Peter  Absolutely, thanks.

Comment: Please change the tag to 'elementary-number-theory'

Answer (score 3):

The proof is by contradiction; it starts by assuming that such a number *does* exist, and then shows that this leads to a contradiction.

Let $D$ be a nine digit number in which every digit occurs except zero, and which ends in $5$, and which is a perfect square. Then $D=A^2$ for some integer $A$, and $A$ ends in $5$ because $D$ ends in $5$. An integer ends in $5$ precisely if it is of the form $10a+5$ for some integer $a$. This is why $A=10a+5$. Then by basic algebra
$$A^2=(10a+5)^2=100a^2+100a+25=100a(a+1)+25.$$
This shows that the last two digits of $A$ are $25$. Then by crudely checking all $10$ cases, the author verifies that the last digit of $a(a+1)$ is always either $0$, $2$ or $6$. As $A^2$ does not contain a digit $0$, and already contains a digit $2$ in the second place, the third digit must be $6$, so $A^2$ ends in $625$. Correspondingly $a\equiv2,7\pmod{10}$ and so $A$ ends in either $25$ or $75$.

Comment: Actually We are considering $D$ to be the nine digit number as well as a square so,$D=A^2$ ,$D$ ends in $5$ so as $A$ ....but we dont know the number of digits of $A$ ,although we know $D$ to be a nine digit ...let's say $A$ is an n digit number $n\leq 9$ so $A=10^{n-1}a_{n-1}+....+5$  so,$A=10(10^{n-2}a_{n-1}+....+a_1)+5$...so $a=(10^{n-2}a_{n-1}+....+a_1)$...$A=10a+5$...if$ A^2=100a(a+1)+25 $...Now if $a(a+1)=6 $ so,$100.6+25=A$...but this just does'nt make any sense.....is $a=(10^{n-2}a_{n-1}+....+a_1)$?....

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: Yup...sure.....

Comment: But I am just not getting the idea behind the solution .....

Comment: The number of digits of $A$ is either $4$ or $5$ because $10^8<A^2<10^9$. The argument above shows that $A^2$ ends in $625$, and that $a$ ends in either $25$ or $75$.

Comment: Where have u shown a contradiction? Or are we supposed to keep on continuing the process?

Comment: @AlanAbraham The text quoted by OP is clearly incomplete and full of (copying) errors, I just attempted to clarify that piece of text.

Comment: @Servaes Well,I was not asking about the number of digits of $A$  and "clearly" I have not intended to reflect upon your text or anything like that...it's just that I am just confused by the idea stated by me above which is not anything " quoted " "clearly" and it seems that you haven't quite got what I am trying to convey through  the "piece of text".....it's just that I want to know what is the value of $a$ ? Is it the one stated by me? If that's it, how can $6$ be the third to last digit...cause its gotta be the nth digit if $a$ is an $n$  digit number....

Comment: @Franklin Okay.